# Should I upgrade to 10.10 now or wait a while longer?

Tags: 10.10, upgrade

I use netbook edition of Ubuntu and I am quite happy. Should I migrate now?

Comment: You may wish to try the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/) or [IRC](http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community) for questions of this nature (Discussion/Objective). For more information on questions which work best on this site see our [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq)

Comment: Or off course our own http://chat.askubuntu.com!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is really: it depends.

If you are very happy with all the software you are using now, and you are using your netbook very regularly, I would not see any reason to update now (or even in the future). You can just stick to the LTS versions.

On the other hand, if you like me want to have the newest software, or just a piece of software that is not available for your version, it is ok to upgrade. The upgrades of ubuntu are really smooth and the change of breaking something  is not big. There is however a change, so just weigh your risks.

For now, there is really a new interface for the netbook. I would suggest using a live-usb to test the new version whether you like it or not and decide based on that.

Answer (score 2):

Not everybody likes the new Unity netbook interface, so you might want to test it first from a live medium (live-CD or live-USB).

Otherwise, upgrading should be fine, although some people prefer to wait a couple of weeks (some bugs found around or after the release will be fixed by then).